# Update GUI Control from background worker thread and from a base class

Tags: vb.net, thread-safety, controls

Hy there!

First. I have read a lot of the other related questions but none responds to my question(s)

---

I have a Winform application which makes some tests on some devices and also logs the progress. And let's make an example.

UI is the main form.

from UI I start a background worker. And inside it I make the tests.

A is the base class.
B inherits the A and adds more methods.

My purpose is to log messages from:
- the mainform UI
- from the background worker DoWork method
- from the B class
- from the A class

I can do this except for the last case. It seems that another rich text box is created, which has the text but is never displayed...

I have created a module called "Logger", which has some functions that will log into a file, show a dialog and log into a richtextbox (or a control)

Example code for understanding and trying  :

```
Public Shared frm As MainForm
Public Shared bgW As BackgroundWorker
Public Shared syncContext As SynchronizationContext

Public Sub New() ' construtor of the main form
' This call is required by the designer.
InitializeComponent()
frm = Me
bgW = bgWorker
syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current
End Sub

Public Module Logger

''' Logs messages into a log file. Each day a new log file is made.
Public Sub Log(message As String, Optional messageType As MessageType = MessageType.ErrorMessage)

Try
Catch ex As Exception
End Try

End Sub

' here goes the method the logs into the control. Examples in the ''approaches'' section

End Module


Public Class A

Public Sub LogA()
Logger.Log("someting")
End Sub

End Class

Public CLass B
Inherits A

Public Sub LogB()
Logger.Log("nothing")
End Sub

Public Sub Do()
MyBase.LogA()
End Sub

End Class

Public Class Test
public Sub Run()

Dim bObj as new B()
bObj.LogB()
bObj.Do()

End Sub

End Class


Private Sub BtnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
Logger.Log("inside click")
bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BgWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgWorker.DoWork
Logger.Log("inside do work")

Dim t as new Test()
t.Run()

End Sub
```

**Approach 1**

Use thread safe

```
 Dim tempForm As Form
Public Sub Log(destinationControl As RichTextBox, mainForm As Form, message As String, messageType As MessageType, Optional textColor As Color = Nothing, Optional textFont As Font = Nothing)
        ' cross operation exception
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message) Then
            tempForm = mainForm
            LogInRichTextBox(destinationControl, message, messageType, textColor, textFont)
        End If

End Sub

  Private Sub LogInRichTextBox(destinationControl As RichTextBox, message As String, messageType As MessageType, Optional textColor As Color = Nothing, Optional textFont As Font = Nothing)

    If destinationControl.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim myDelegate As New LogInBoxDelegate(AddressOf LogInRichTextBox)
        tempForm.Invoke(myDelegate, New Object() {destinationControl, message, messageType, textColor, textFont})
    Else
        destinationControl.AppendText(vbCrLf)
    End If

End Sub
```

**Approach 2**

Use shared variable

```
  Public Sub Log( mainForm As Form, message As String, messageType As MessageType, Optional textColor As Color = Nothing, Optional textFont As Font = Nothing)
        ' cross operation exception
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message) Then
            tempForm = mainForm
            LogInRichTextBox(message, messageType, textColor, textFont)
        End If

End Sub

  Private Sub LogInRichTextBox(message As String, messageType As MessageType, Optional textColor As Color = Nothing, Optional textFont As Font = Nothing)

    If  MainForm.frm.rtbMessageLog.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim myDelegate As New LogInBoxDelegate(AddressOf LogInRichTextBox)
        tempForm.Invoke(myDelegate, New Object() { MainForm.frm.rtbMessageLog, message, messageType, textColor, textFont})
    Else
        MainForm.frm.rtbMessageLog.AppendText(vbCrLf)
    End If

End Sub
```

**Approach 3**
Use background worker 'report progress'

```
 Public Sub Log( mainForm As Form, message As String, messageType As MessageType, Optional textColor As Color = Nothing, Optional textFont As Font = Nothing)
        ' cross operation exception
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message) Then
            tempForm = mainForm
            LogInRichTextBox(message, messageType, textColor, textFont)
        End If

End Sub

  Private Sub LogInRichTextBox(message As String, messageType As MessageType, Optional textColor As Color = Nothing, Optional textFont As Font = Nothing)

    MainForm.bgW.ReportProgress(0,message)

End Sub

     Private Sub BgWorker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgWorker.ProgressChanged

               rtbMessageLog.AppendText(CStr(e.UserState))

    End Sub
```

**Approach 4**
Use Syncronization Context

```
Public Sub Log( mainForm As Form, message As String, messageType As MessageType, Optional textColor As Color = Nothing, Optional textFont As Font = Nothing)
        ' cross operation exception
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message) Then
            tempForm = mainForm
            LogInRichTextBox(message, messageType, textColor, textFont)
        End If

End Sub

  Private Sub LogInRichTextBox(message As String, messageType As MessageType, Optional textColor As Color = Nothing, Optional textFont As Font = Nothing)

    MainForm.syncContext.Post(New Threading.SendOrPostCallback(Sub() MainForm.rtbMessageLog.AppendText(message)), Nothing)

End Sub
```

So, the request is:

I want to update my rtbMessageLog.Text from class A (or the base class - see example code)

Thank you

Comment: That's a lot to digest, but perhaps you should separate the Logger module from how the message is displayed.  e.g. Perhaps your original `Public Sub Log(message As String, Optional messageType As MessageType = MessageType.ErrorMessage)` could raise an event that you can handle in the MainForm class to update the RTB or display a message box (using InvokeRequired etc. to get on the UI thread), and you could handle it somewhere else to log to a file etc.  Just throwing out ideas at the moment!

Comment: Agreed.  Your Class A and B should raise an **Event** that the Form subscribes to.  When received, I'd use either Invoke() or the SynchronizationContext approach to update the UI...**but** you'd use direct references to the Form/Control because you are already there (as that is where the event is received).  You wouldn't need any of the Shared members at all.

Comment: Thank you, for your ideas... I will try to implement them in a few hours... Never thought to use events...

Answer (score 1):

With help of comments of @Mark and @Idle_Mind, I have succeeded in finding a solution. Thank you so much

I post some code, maybe it will help others:

```
Public Module Logger

    Public Event LogInRichTextBoxEvent(message As String, textColor As Color, textFont As Font)
    Delegate Sub LogInBoxDelegate(message As String, textColor As Color, textFont As Font)

    ''' Logs messages into a log file. Each day a new log file is made.
    Public Sub Log(message As String, Optional messageType As MessageType = MessageType.ErrorMessage)
        Try
         RaiseEvent LogInRichTextBoxEvent(message, textColor, textFont)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub

    ' here goes the method the logs into the control. Examples in the ''approaches'' section

End Module

Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        AddHandler Logger.LogInRichTextBoxEvent, AddressOf ShouldLoggerHandler
    catch ex as exception
    End try
End Sub

Private Sub ShouldLoggerHandler(message As String, textColor As Color, textFont As Font)
    If rtbMessageLog.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim myDelegate As New LogInBoxDelegate(AddressOf ShouldLoggerHandler)
        Me.Invoke(myDelegate, New Object() {message, textColor, textFont})
    Else
        rtbMessageLog.AppendTxet(message)
    End if
End Sub
```